# Pop up an alert when someone tries to check out a project that is already checked out by someone else

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, tfvc

I want to pop up an alert when someone tries to check out a project/file that is already checked out by someone else on TFS, Visual Studio 2012.

Let's say I checked out a file and let others to check out but prevent from check in. When someone else tried to check out same file, pop up should inform them about my checkout, but they can still checkout and try some changes. I searched the web but couldn't find a solution for that.

I know we can look for current checkouts form VS console with *tf status* command, but I'm looking for something visual when they tried to check out.

Answer (score -1):

One way to achieve this is to use a version control system such as Git or TFS (Team Foundation Server) that supports file locking. In TFS, you can use the "tf lock" command to lock a file so that only you can check it out. When someone else tries to check out the locked file, they will receive an error message telling them that the file is locked.

Another way is to create a script or program that periodically checks the status of the files in the repository and displays a pop-up message if a file is already checked out by someone else. This script can be run on the client side as a background process or on the server side as a service.
You can use the TFS API to check for check-out status and trigger the alert accordingly.

It's also worth noting that some integrated development environments (IDEs) such as Visual Studio have built-in functionality for displaying file lock status, so you may want to check if the functionality is available in your chosen IDE before implementing a custom solution.

Comment: Sorry I didn't explicitly say that I'm using TFS on Visual Studio, I don't want to lock others from checking out. I choose that others can checkout but can not check-in. Even though, when they try to check out, I want the to be informed about that I have a checkout.